# Extending UserManager to allow for management of new user data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, usermanager

UserManager in ASPNET Identity contains functions like `AddPasswordAsync` and `SetPhoneNumberAsync`.

I've added properties for FirstName and LastName who's values weren't set when I registered the user so I want to add screens to Manage these values (setting and changing them).

How can I extend UserManager to add a function like `AddNamesAsync` that will do this?

Such a function becomes necessary when we evaluate the ManageController actions as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Along the same logic, I'd like to add a function to the controller as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetNames(SetUserFullNamesViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await UserManager.AddNamesAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.FirstName, model.LastName);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetNamesSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

How can I add a function to UserManager or extend UserManager so that I can add the function that'll allow me to update add and update custom property values on the user?

Comment: UserManager is meant to be inherited. Create your class, inherit UserManager, add whatever functions you need.

Answer (score 3):

First add `custom columns` to `AppliicationUser` class

and then you can update `custom columns` like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetNames(SetUserFullNamesViewModel model)
{
    ApplicationUser usermodel = UserManager.FindById(user.Id);
    usermodel.Name = model.Name;
    usermodel.Surname = model.Surname;


    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(usermodel);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ListUser", "User");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of methods that I don't know even exist on the .net framework but I guess practice make experience. Thank you